# Java Wicket Form : Error serializing object class 'myClassName'

Tags: java, forms, listview, serialization, wicket

I have the following Wicked Form (List). The point of the forms is to enter a comment message and onSubmit save it to a Database.

```
List<List<String>> modalHTML = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> modalIDlist = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> modalCounter = new ArrayList<>();
//...
final ListView listview = new ListView("modalListview", modalCounter) {
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            Integer index = (Integer)item.getModelObject();

            final Label labelDiv = new Label("modalHTML1", modalHTML.get(index).get(0));
            labelDiv.setEscapeModelStrings(false);

            final Label labelDiv2 = new Label("modalHTML2", modalHTML.get(index).get(1));
            labelDiv2.setEscapeModelStrings(false);

            item.add(labelDiv);
            item.add(labelDiv2);

            //Create Form

            final TextArea<String> textAreaComment = new TextArea<>("textAreaComment", Model.of(""));

            final TextField<String> ffFileNameComment = new TextField<>("TfFileNameComment", Model.of(""));
            final TextField<String> tfFileAdressComment = new TextField<>("TfFileAdressComment", Model.of(""));     

            if(isUser) {
                tfFileNameComment.add(new AttributeModifier("style", "display: none;"));
                TfFileAdressComment.add(new AttributeModifier("style", "display: none;"));
            }

            final HiddenField<String> hiddenIDfield = new HiddenField<>("hiddenIDfield", Model.of(modalIDlist.get(index)+""));


            final Form<?> commentForm = new Form<Void>("commentForm") {
                @Override
                protected void onSubmit() {
                    String text = (String)textAreaComment.getModelObject();
                    String id = (String)hiddenIDfield.getModelObject();
                    System.out.println("Comment eingegeben: "+text+ " - id: "+id);

                    //write comment
                    try {
                        app.getUserDb().addComment(Integer.parseInt(id), user_name, text);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Error form submit");
                    }

                };
            };

            commentForm.add(textAreaComment);
            commentForm.add(hiddenIDfield);
            commentForm.add(tfFileNameComment);
            commentForm.add(tfFileAdressComment);

            item.add(commentForm);

        }
    };
    add(listview);
```

The line :

```
app.getUserDb().addComment(Integer.parseInt(id), user_name, text);
```

is causing the problem. When loading the page the NotSerializableException error will occur in the Console (Page is still loading). When i remove this line the Error won't occur.

```
18:53:09.051 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] WARN  org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream - error delegating to writeObject : ."classpasth".WorkflowJDBC, path: /children
18:53:09.054 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] ERROR org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer - Error serializing object class ."classpasth".BSWModuleOverview [object=[Page class = ."classpasth".BSWModuleOverview, id = 2, render count = 1]]
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: A problem occurred while trying to collect debug information about not serializable object
    at org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer$SerializationCheckerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(JavaSerializer.java:282) ~[wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer.serialize(JavaSerializer.java:78) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AbstractPageStore.serializePage(AbstractPageStore.java:133) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DefaultPageStore.createSerializedPage(DefaultPageStore.java:281) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DefaultPageStore.storePage(DefaultPageStore.java:61) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.page.PageStoreManager$PersistentRequestAdapter.storeTouchedPages(PageStoreManager.java:403) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.page.RequestAdapter.commitRequest(RequestAdapter.java:193) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.page.AbstractPageManager.commitRequest(AbstractPageManager.java:76) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.page.PageManagerDecorator.commitRequest(PageManagerDecorator.java:74) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.page.PageAccessSynchronizer$2.commitRequest(PageAccessSynchronizer.java:270) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Application$3.onDetach(Application.java:1786) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$3.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:105) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$3.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:101) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection$1.notify(ListenerCollection.java:120) [wicket-util-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.reversedNotify(ListenerCollection.java:144) [wicket-util-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.reversedNotifyIgnoringExceptions(ListenerCollection.java:113) [wicket-util-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection.onDetach(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:100) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.onDetach(RequestCycle.java:645) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.detach(RequestCycle.java:594) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:297) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284) [wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494) [catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137) [catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651) [catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.7]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.7]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: ."classpasth".WorkflowJDBC
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.internalWriteEntries(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:675) ~[wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer$SerializationCheckerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(JavaSerializer.java:271) ~[wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: ."classpasth".WorkflowJDBC
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.internalWriteEntries(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer$SerializationCheckerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(JavaSerializer.java:260) ~[wicket-core-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
    ... 79 more
18:53:09.065 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] WARN  org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AbstractPageStore - Page [Page class = ."classpasth".BSWModuleOverview, id = 2, render count = 1] cannot be serialized. See previous logs for possible reasons.
18:53:09.065 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] WARN  org.apache.wicket.pageStore.DefaultPageStore - Page [Page class = ."classpasth".BSWModuleOverview, id = 2, render count = 1] cannot be serialized. See previous logs for possible reasons.
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: just a note: please stick to the Java Naming Conventions and don't start variables with a captial. Prefer `tfFileNameComment` over `TfFileNameComment` (this is also fix the code highlighting in your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem:
For my class 'WorkflowJDBC' and all dependent classes i did not implemented "Serializable".
After i implemented Serializable the error  did not occur.

I now wonder why the error didn't occur when i had the line

```
app.getUserDb().addComment(Integer.parseInt(id), user_name, text);
```

removed. Because it has not any connection to the class 'WorkflowJDBC'.

Answer (score 0):

In development mode Wicket prints quite detailed error message for `NotSerializableException`. It prints a tree-like pointing the to exact member field which is not serializable.

If you have gave us the real class name and full error message then we would be able to tell you what exactly is the problem!

Comment: " A problem occurred while trying to collect debug information about not serializable object". It seems there is some problem that breaks Wicket's machinery (SerializationCheckerObjectOutputStream) to give you the nice error message. It seems `WorkflowJDBC` is problematic but I cannot tell you how exactly.